# Flowable and Activiti pricing

Tags: activiti, bpmn, flowable

I am trying to explore different BPM tools and how open source they are.

- For Camunda, I was able to find detailed articles ([article 1](https://camunda.com/blog/2022/05/how-open-is-camunda-platform-8/), [article 2](https://camunda.com/pricing/)).
- For Flowable, I could find only [this link](https://www.flowable.com/pricing), does this mean nothing is available in the free version?
- For Activiti, I could not find any related articles.
- For jBPM, it looks like everything is free except for the support.

Could someone please help with the pricing details for Activity, Flowable?

Answer (score 0):

For Flowable the engines (BPMN, CMMN and DMN) are open source, the productivity tools are licensed. However, you can use the Flowable Design Cloud for free with the Open Source models. You can find out more information about that in the [blog post about the 7.0.0 release](https://www.flowable.com/blog/engineering/flowable-open-source-7-0-0-release). The source code and further information can be found [at Github](https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine).